# About while loop

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

The following code just 'hangs up' my game, I am using javascript with `craftyjs` .. I think I am doing very noob mistake which is resulting into infinite loop ..

```
var trigger_de_movement=true;
pl.animate('PlayerMovingLeft', 1, 1); //this function starts animation named PlayerMovingLeft for 1 frame and repeates 1 time..
while (trigger_de_movement) {/*if animation is not playing, type time and go out and stop the loop*/
    if (!pl.isPlaying('PlayerMovingLeft')) {//checks if animation is playing for pl(ayer)
        var d=new Date();
        putMessage(d.getSeconds()+"."+d.getMilliseconds()); //this function puts message
        trigger_de_movement=false; //to make while loop not run forever
    }
}
```

Comment: If the condition fails, the loop will be infinite

Answer (score 0):

The problem is,

```
if(!pl.isPlaying('PlayerMovingLeft'))
```

If the `If statement` fails, then the loop will be infinite, because the variable `trigger_de_movement` is true always until the if statement becomes true. If it is false, the loop is infinite. So better you change your `while to If` and check what happening

Comment: BUT...if the condition fails, loop would run again right? But the animation should stop after some time (I want to figure out that time..that's why I am showing message about the time) so when the lopp is 'looping' at some instant, it should stop when animation has stopped moving..am I wrong? and are there any other ways to know animation speed?